Template-driven forms cannot capture data from dynamically added form controls
I have a list of categories where users can edit their titles and then submit or cancel the changes.
[
 {
 "title": "Personal",
 "color": "#ff6b6b"
 },
 {
 "title": "Work",
 "color": "#66d9e8"
 },
 {
 "title": "List 1",
 "color": "#ffd43b"
 }
]

Initially, I chose to use template-driven forms for this functionality.
To achieve this, I first created a template for the category inputs. These inputs are similar in some ways, but their number may vary.
<ng-template let-nature="nature" let-item="item" #t>
  <input type="text" ngModel attr.name="{{ item.title }}" />
</ng-template>

I then included this template for each category and imported the necessary Forms module.
<div class="container">
  <h1>Settings</h1>
  <div class="lists">
    <h2>Lists</h2>
    <form
      id="categories"
      class="column gap-1"
      ngForm
      #categoriesForm="ngForm"
      (ngSubmit)="saveCategories(categoriesForm)"
    >
      <input type="text" ngModel name="username" />
      <ng-container *ngFor="let category of placeholders.categories">
        <ng-container
          *ngTemplateOutlet="t; context: { item: category, nature: 'category' }"
        ></ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </form>

    <div class="buttons row gap-half">
      <button type="submit" form="categories" class="btn primary-btn">
        Save
      </button>
      <button class="btn secondary-btn">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Note: I created an input with the attribute name set to "username" for testing purposes. I then compared the results.
The submit function is
 saveCategories(categories: NgForm) {
    console.log(categories);
  }

Everything seems to be working correctly so far. The form is created, ngForm is added,ngModel too and name attribute is set appropriately.
The problem, as I mentioned before, is that the categories form only captures the 'username' input. I'm unsure why this is happening.
Take a look at:
DOM elements

Console output

I'm new to Angular and I'm interested in practicing template-driven forms with ng-template, ng-container, and different directive types (structural and attribute directives). I'm using this example to practice, but I'm feeling overwhelmed by an error I can't seem to solve. I've searched for solutions but haven't found any yet.

I tried embedding the content of the template directly into the form, and it worked as expected. However, I'm curious about the cause of the issue with ngTemplateOutlet. What's happening behind the scenes that leads to this different behavior?
